# Importing React Components with ES6

Tags: reactjs, import, components

I have a react component, in login.js , that I am keeping in a separate file, and then importing login.js in my main file, App.js. I'm having trouble with the importing, as the localhost page I'm rendering the app to just shows up completely blank, with no errors given. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, the code for my component, login.js is below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';


class login extends Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {emailText: '',
                  passwordText: ''
                 }
}


onChangeEmail(e) {
    this.setState({emailText: e.target.value})
}

onChangePassword(e) {
    this.setState({passwordText: e.target.value})
}

signUpUser(){
    console.log(this.state.emailText)
    console.log(this.state.passwordText)

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.emailText, this.state.passwordText)
    console.log('New account created, and is now signed in.')
}

loginUser(){
    console.log('logging in rn')
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.emailText, this.state.passwordText)
    console.log('Successfully logged in')
}

logoutUser(){
    firebase.auth().signOut()
    console.log('logged out')
}

    render(){
        return  (
            <div class="container">
            <input onChange={this.onChangeEmail.bind(this)} id="txtEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email"/>

            <input onChange={this.onChangePassword.bind(this)} id="txtPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password"></input>       

            <button onClick={this.loginUser.bind(this)} id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-action">
            Log in </button>    

            <button onClick={this.signUpUser.bind(this)} id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-secondary">
            Sign Up </button>

            <button onClick={this.logoutUser.bind(this)} id="btnLogout" class="btn btn-action hide">Log Out</button>
        </div>  
        )

    }

};

export default login;
```

The code I am importing login.js into is below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase'; // Import Firebase library
import login from './login.js';

export default class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <login/>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

My index.js is below:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: Change `login` to `Login` and see what happens. Relevant [info](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4695).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the name of the `login` component. It needs to be `Login` instead of `login`.

Here is the case when it's named `Login` and everything works fine:

https://codesandbox.io/s/EkEJ02zY

Try to change it from `Login` to `login` and you'll get blank screen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fixed it! All I did was change the name of my component to uppercase, and in my App.js there was a missing semicolon. 2 hours well spent lol